# Syntax error when trying to filter users using Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, filter, active-directory

Good day,

Right now I'm writing a Powershell script to add users to a group from a CSV. The CSV contains the user's Name and only that. There's no second column or headers, the file is formatted like below:

```
JOHN.SMITH
JANE.DOE
FRED.EXAMPLE
```

I've written the following code to make the changes I want, but it throws a syntax error on Get-ADUser and I can't figure out why.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$UsersFile = Import-CSV "D:\Migrations\UsersForTestGroup.csv" -Header Name
Foreach($UserHeader in $UsersFile)
{
    $UserEntry = ($UserHeader -split '=',2 | select -last 1) -split '\ ',2 | select -first 1
    # This removes the header and trailing space and bracket that were there from the CSV import
    $User = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like $UserEntry"
    # This should then use that name to search for the correct $User but instead throws a syntax error
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Test Group" -Members $User
}
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'Name -like JOHN.SMITH' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '12'.
At line:5 char:9
+ $User = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like $UserEntry"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Micr
   osoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

My guess is there's something causing the filter to not properly consider $UserEntry as a string, but I can't figure out how to fix that.

Comment: `"Name -Like '$var'"`. Needs to be quoted.

Comment: Your example is splitting the string at the `slash` but there are no slashes in your Name column. Is that an issue with your example or something else?

Comment: It's an escape character for the whitespace character that comes after it. I'm certain it splits the string correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with your example and question as the `Get-Content` cmdlet does not support the `-Header` parameter. I used this to test your example:

```
$UsersFile = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\test.csv" -Header Name
    Foreach($UserHeader in $UsersFile.Name){    # Note the change here to use $variable.Name
        # Line below is not needed as there are no "\" slashes
        # $UserEntry = ($UserHeader -split '=',2 | select -last 1) -split '\ ',2 | select -first 1
Write-Host $UserEntry}
```

I suspect the issue is with your example though as your error shows you have the `JOHN.SMITH` username correctly formatted. Assuming that is accurate, I believe the real issue is on the line:

```
$User = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like $UserEntry"
```

Which should look like this instead:

```
$User = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "$UserEntry"'
```

Comment: the filter needs to be quoted along with the condition to match: `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$UserEntry'"`, otherwise it's improper syntax and reads each token as part of the cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks @AbrahamZinala, I was not familiar with the syntax for the `-Filter` parameter & I corrected my answer. But I think you have the single/[double quotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#double-quoted-strings) reversed in your comment. Also `Get-ADUser` [Example2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-2-get-a-filtered-list-of-users)

Comment: Double quotes in PowerShell allow for interpolation to occur. As of now, you current suggestion will look for a literal ad object with the name of `$UserEntry` and not the value of the variable inside; ex. `Joe`. Single quotes are for literal readings whereas double quotes allow variable expansion. `$var = "foo"; "$var",'$var'`, this shows you just that.